# What is the processing order of functions and strings?

Tags: php

## Summary

I want a function to execute only if a certain variable is `true`, however it checks the status of the variable *before* it exists.

## Code

At the top of my PHP page I have:

```
$debug = true;
```

At the bottom, among other functions I have:

```
function debug($message){
    echo ($debug ? "$message<br/>" : "");
}
```

And throughout the page I call:

```
debug("Debugging message here");
```

However, when I run the page with error reporting on, I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: debug in /examle.php on line 148

which references the middle line of the function.

## Question

How can I make a function that prints data only if the variable `$debug`, which is called at the top of the page, is `true`?

Comment: The variable `$debug` is [out of scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) in the function `debug()`.... that's why we pass arguments to functions

Comment: What you have found is a variable scope

Comment: You can either send `$debug` as a parameter or use `global $debug;` inside your function. I'd recommend not using `global`

Comment: Why would you recommend not using `global`? Is there a third alternative that avoids me having to send it as a parameter each time the function is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function debug($message){
    global $debug;
    echo ($debug ? "$message<br/>" : "");
}
```

You need to access the global var else it checks for a local one

Comment: The "corecter" way would be to pass `$debug` into the function rather than making in global. Just saying.

Comment: Why is making a variable global bad practice?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making it global, obviously, the word `global` is there for a reason. It just hides dependencies, makes debugging a little harder too. But then again this is a little subjective. It's your call I guess.